# can't attach screen shots to mocha allure reporter for protractor tests

Tags: typescript, protractor, mocha.js, ui-automation, allure

I am trying to attach screenshots to allure report. I don't get any error but the report does not show any screenshot

```
"mocha-allure-reporter": "1.4.0",
```

Here is the testbase.ts

```
import { login_Page } from '../pageObjects/LL1_loginPage'
import { browser } from 'protractor'
declare const allure: any;
before(function () {
  login_Page.login()
  browser.sleep(3000)
  login_Page.pageLoadConfirmation()
})
afterEach(function () {
  allure.createStep('initial', () => {
    browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) { allure.createAttachment('title', new Buffer(png, 'base64')); })
    console.log("successful")
  });
})
```

mocha set up in config file

```
mochaOpts: {
  slow: 90000,
    timeout: 180000,
      reporter: 'mocha-allure-reporter'
},
framework: 'mocha',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you.

`afterEach(async function () {
    const png = await browser.takeScreenshot();
    allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', new Buffer(png, 'base64'), 'image/png');
})`

Answer (score 0):

Acheived through below code

```
 afterEach(async function(){
    const png = await browser.takeScreenshot()
    allure.createAttachment('screenshot',new Buffer(png,'base64'),'image/png')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without the Deprecated Buffer issue:

```
afterEach(async function() {
const png = await browser.takeScreenshot();
allure.createAttachment("Screenshot", Buffer.from(png, "base64"), "image/png");
});
```